# How to detect segment count in site path using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect the count of segments in the path of site. If the user is currently in a page like the URL below:

```
example.com/foo/bar/
```

I want to know that this site path includes 2 URI segments. I want to get '2' using javascript. Doing so, I want to create a new path like this somewhere in my code and get 2 segments back (sometimes 3 segments or so according to the site path) to have `files.json` which is located in root folder:

```
../../files.json
```

Is there a way to do it with javascript?!

Comment: Why not just start the URL with `/` and start from the top? i.e. `/files.json`

Comment: No, you'll have to configure that on your server. There are lots of different types of "folders" including arbitrary values that dynamically generate content, so it would be difficult to "count" in that case, seeing as there's virtually infinite folders possible in that scenario.

Comment: @Quentin You mean, it doesn't matter in which segment the user is and we can get back to the root by `/` ? Am I right?!

Comment: Not certain interpret _"I want to create a new path like this somewhere in my code and get 2 segments back (sometimes 3 segments or so according to the site path)"_ correctly ? What is expected result ?

Answer (score -2):

Whi don't you just use the *window.location.hostname* which is the root URL?

```
var rootURL = window.location.hostname;
```

Of course, it will depend on whether the website is hosted in the root directory of the domain or not.